# System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException was unhandled: is not a valid path

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, ms-access

This is my first attempt trying to access db files from the server. If run the program locally there are no problems

I stored ms access files on the server and I trying to run the program from my laptop and I am recieving the following error....

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException was unhandled is not a valid path.  Make sure that the path 
name is spelled correctly and that you are connected to the server on which the file resides.
```

My connection string looks something like this...

```
myCon = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=H:\name-SERVER\SHAREDFILES\FileRDB.mdb; Jet OLEDB:System Database=system.mdw");
```

There has username and password for the server. Should I include this in the connection string?

Stacktrace looks like this...

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException was unhandled
   is not a valid path.  Make sure that the path name is spelled correctly and that you are connected to the server on which the file resides.
  Source=Microsoft JET Database Engine
  ErrorCode=-2147467259
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString constr, OleDbConnection connection)
       at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)
       at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup)
       at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
       at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
       at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open()
       at MALHRManagementSystem.FrmLogin.btnLogin_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\username\Desktop\Project\foldername\foldername\foldername\Form.cs:line 40
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       at somefilename.Program.Main() in C:\Users\username\Desktop\Project\foldername\foldername\foldername\Program.cs:line 18
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Please can someone advise me how do I correct this problem.

Thanks in advance

I am not sure what tag I should use for this thread but please correct it if I am wrong here.

db is MS-Access 2003 and visual studio 2010

Comment: If you put the file path in a file explorer , will it directs to your db?

Comment: I you are not sure how the connection string is constructed use http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: Is that `H:` drive a network drive? That drive mapping is user dependent, so if you app now runs as a different user, that mapping is missing. Use a UNC path (\\server\folder) instead.

Comment: I did not think of file path in file explorer. I will try that tomorrow because I am not there. Connectiondtrings website I know about. I was just wondering if there was anything that needs to be done on the network side?

Comment: @HansKesting - I don't know if the H: is a network drive ? I don't know about about UNC path (\\server\folder). Is possible you could explain this work advise a website etc. thanks

Comment: @bucketblast - in Windows Explorer, in the "My Computer" view I have a list of "drives" in several groups. One group is "Network Location" - there are mapped network drives. See also [connectionstrings for Access](http://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-jet-ole-db-4-0/network-location/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working now. To have a mapped network drive on vista/ Windows 7. Right click on My Computer > Map Network Drive > Select a drive > Click on Browse button . A menu appears as Browse For Folder -- Select a shared network folder. Then choose the network name and the folder. Once you have done that Click OK. That is all you have to do. Here are some useful links on howto if anyone is interested...

[here](http://www.google.co.uk/#q=mapped+network+drive+)

[here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows7/Create-a-shortcut-to-map-a-network-drive)

[Vista](http://www.google.co.uk/#q=mapped+network+drive+vista)